# python urllib2 requests session

Tags: python, linux

how can i set the authentication to session based on this script so that additional URL's dont require re-auth?

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import urllib2
import base64
import json
import requests

def proc():
    request = urllib2.Request("https://192.168.174.163:9443/restapi/server/api/v2/cluster")
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ("admin", "admin")).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    cookie = result.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
    data = result.read()
    print data
    #convert json data to python dictionary
    json_decoded = json.loads(data)
    print json_decoded
    #cluster name
    print json_decoded["name"]


def main():
    proc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you import the `requests` module but don't do anything with it?

Comment: would be good if you can refill it :)

Comment: *"because I'm lazy"* - Well, there's your problem. **Stop guesssing APIs**, and instead read the docs on the modules you want to use - either [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/) or [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) (I suggest the former).

Comment: why did you suggest the former?

Comment: Because it's easier and cleaner to use than `urllib`, particularly when it comes to HTTPS, authentication and cookie / [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) handling. It's not magic though, you still have to read its documentation.